# Netbeans Maven Project Not adding Main Class to Manifest

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, deployment, netbeans-7

I am having a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266735/no-main-manifest-attribute-in-jar-netbeans) question. I have tried all the suggestions listed and am still at a loss. My issue is that I am trying to build a maven project and distribute it to other machines, but the jar files are not being populated with a correct Manifest. Each time I build and run I get the following error: `no main manifest attribute, in myjar.jar`. Is there some sort of configuration file I need to edit? I just don't know what is going on. I have attempted [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848642/how-to-setup-main-class-in-manifest-file-in-jar-produced-by-netbeans-project) also, but to no avail.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add it into project's pom file, inside `<project>` tag:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.4</version>
          <configuration>
              <archive>
                  <manifest>
                      <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
              </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You know how many of these hacks I had to use to make a Netbeans Java Maven project run like a Netbeans Java Ant project? Why don't they make this more seamless?

Comment: Don't try to make it look like ant. Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration to keep your software as maven standard project to avoid custom configurations.

Comment: How else do you assume I create a distributable jar file with dependencies ?  I need a lib folder with the dependency jars, and I need an executable jar that includes the classpath to that folder, and I need that jar to know what the main class is. None of these features come out of the box for a maven project. Has nothing to do with conventions.

Answer (score 30):

Another option is to use the `maven shade plugin`. Unlike the `maven jar plugin` showed by tigran, the `maven shade plugin` includes your dependencies in the generated jar.
A sample usage of the plugin is :

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>your.main.Class</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first two answers, I suggest people add it as a "Code Template" within the NetBeans settings. It will autocomplete once you type in a keyword and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This may be a feature that was unavailable at the time of this post.

[NetBeans Maven POM Code Template Expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpB1c.png)

In the linked picture you can see what my template autocompletes when I type `assembly` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It fills in (where *${MC newVarName default="${exec.mainClass}"}* dynamically points to the mainClass):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <!-- NOTE: We don't need a groupId specification because the group is
            org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.
        -->
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```