# Maven and Netbeans: how do I build project and get executable jar?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, executable-jar

I've just started standard Maven -> Java Application in Netbeans 7.4.
It created "App" class (which has main method) by default. I also went to project's Properties->Run and set that class as a Main Class. I then built the project.

In the project's directory, I got the "target" folder with a couple of jars inside. None of them is the executable one. How do I simply fix the problem and get the executable jar at the end of each build?

thanks.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282098/netbeans-maven-project-not-adding-main-class-to-manifest

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This may be a little lack of integration between Netbeans and Maven.

Doing "Properties->Run and set that Main Class" in the IDE doesn't make Maven to set the main class in the `MANIFEST.MF` of the generated jar: you have to explicitly say to Maven which is the main class by adding the `<mainClass>` tag to the `configuration` of the `maven-jar-plugin`.

For example if your `pom.xml` were:

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.taringamberini</groupId>
    <artifactId>AppTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.taringamberini.apptest.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

than in the `target` directory you would find the `AppTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, and you should be able to run:

```
AppTest/target$java -jar AppTest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Hello World!
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. It solved the problem. Besides, I was convinced that the jar will run as soon as I double-click it. Now it seems that I had to run the "java -jar (...)" command.

Comment: Can this code compile external libraries into one jar file together with the original jar?

Comment: @YoungMillie as far as I know no, it can't. I guess you are looking for [fat jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).