# Main class not generated in manifest file

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

The problem I have is that when I build a project and then tries to run the jar file nothing happens. When I run `java -jar Tried-1.jar` I get this error message:
`no main manifest attribute, in Tried-1.jar`

I have open the jar file as an archive and found that the `Main-Class:` line in the `MANIFEST.MF` file doesn't exist. I have checked an older project that I built in Netbeans 12.0 and that one runs and has the `Main-Class:` line in its Manifest file.

I tried to build the old project in Netbeans 12.2 and I encounter the same problem that the `Main-Class:` line doesn't exist.

I have tried multiple fixes and none works, deciding what is the main class in project properties doesn't solve the problem, and other solutions to this problem by changing the `pom.xml` file doesn't help either, just causes more problems.

I have also tried to run the class file within the jar file from the command prompt and that works fine.

I have read the documentation for Maven but I couldn't find anything to resolve my problem.

**Update**

I was able to fix the problem by chaning my `pom.xml` file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Tried</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.tried.NewMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

But I still have the problem that I would need to add this every time I create a project, is there a way to make this automatic at every new project?

Netbeans 12.2 | Maven 3.6.3 | Java JDK 15.0.1

Comment: How are you packaging your jar? Is there a tool in Netbeans that does this for you? Previously I've used either a Maven plugin to automate this or have just created the file by hand under META-INF and had it included in the jar

Comment: It does all automatically when I build the project, but I think it's the `maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar`

Comment: what's in your pom.xml file?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer to _“No Main Manifest Attribute” in ----.jar Netbeans_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21224284/2985643) which shows how you can configure **maven-jar-plugin** in your **pom.xml** to specify `<addClasspath>` and `<mainClass>`. But even if that works it doesn't really explain why it is necessary when using 12.2, but not when using 12.0. Or have you also changed your version of **maven-jar-plugin**, or its configuration in **pom.xml**?

Comment: I was able to change the pom.xml file to fix the problem but how do I make it so I don't need to do this every time?

Comment: @SemlanBakelsen Why do you think you _"need to do this every time"_? Just edit your **pom.xml** once to fix the problem, and that is all you need to do. Why is that a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No Main Manifest Attribute" in ----.jar Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266735/no-main-manifest-attribute-in-jar-netbeans)

Comment: @skomisa The problem is that when I create a new project the pom.xml file will not include the main-class lines. And then the jars don't run :/

Comment: @SemlanBakelsen OK, understood. A possible approach might be to use project inheritance with your POMs. Have a parent POM, and inherit from that POM in each project. [See the Maven documentation for details](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance). But you would still have to configure project-specific features of each project within its own POM. Also, since that is a distinct problem from the one you originally raised and have now resolved, please create a new question for any new issues arising if necessary.