# Java can't execute jar file no main manifest attribute

Tags: java

```
jar cvef Main.jar Main *

added manifest
adding: DrawPane.class(in = 344) (out= 257)(deflated 25%)
adding: DrawPane.java(in = 306) (out= 175)(deflated 42%)
adding: main(in = 9038) (out= 8275)(deflated 8%)
adding: Main.class(in = 868) (out= 544)(deflated 37%)
adding: Main.java(in = 507) (out= 260)(deflated 48%)
adding: Manifest.txt(in = 18) (out= 18)(deflated 0%)
adding: src/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: src/icon.png(in = 1163) (out= 1168)(deflated 0%)
adding: src/Thumbs.db(in = 3584) (out= 1038)(deflated 71%)
```

jar file created, then:

```
java -jar Main.jar
```

I get an error:

```
no main manifest attribute, in Main.jar
```

what I'am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: but I'am doing it all right, can't understand why can't find the Manifest attribute? look at the output...

Comment: this is not a duplicate, please can you look at my code and give me an advice on what is not right? because I get a message that "added manifest" but still doesn't find it on executing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute

This is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html) your manifest file should have relative path `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. It doesn't look like you added your own manifest there. The `jar` command adds a default manifest, that's why it says 'manifest added'.

**EDIT**: As per [the next page in the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html), the basic syntax to add content to the manifest file is the following:

```
jar cfm jar-file manifest-addition input-file(s)
```

I recommend to read the first few section of the tutorial and I'm sure you'll get the result you want!

Comment: I've added a folder META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, it is ignoring this file in the output, and still no manifest attribute?

Answer (score 2):

make sure to write 1 space after ":" and new line after class name and save it that way.
jar tool syntax:

```
 jar -cvmf manifest.txt appname.jar ClassName.class
```

after running tool , run jar file with

```
java -jar appname.jar
```

Content of manifest.txt file

Main-Class:(1space)ClassName(press enter for new line)

Hope it helps

Comment: I find it funny how the manifest needs to have a new line at the end. Recently also noticed that the javac tool can't read UTF16LE BOM.