# converting .jar file to .exe in ubuntu

Tags: java

Trying to convert jar file to  executable one on ubuntu 14.04 platform.The executed command is
java -jar bank.jar     ,
it throws msg as
no main manifest attribute, in bank.jar

Kindly help me to fix this issue

Comment: how did you convert your jar to an executable jar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You doon't need to convert jar to executable. You need a manifest file in your jar.
Here you can read about the solution:

[Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)