# no main manifest attribute, in jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, manifest, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to run a jar created by the maven shade plugin. I am configuring the main class the following way:

```
<project>
...
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>org.comany.MainClass</Main-Class>
                <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

...

But when I try running the jar using java -jar app.jar it gives the following error

```
 "no main manifest attribute, in  app.jar"
```

EDIT:
I checked the contents of the jar using jar tf app.jar and I see a MANIFEST.MF file. BUt it does not have the entry for main class. How do I make sure the manifest file in jar has this entry apart for adding it in the shade plugin configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Answer (score 18):

Maven's shade plugin uses the JAR generated by the jar plugin and adds dependencies on it. Since it seems like the transforms on the shade plugin do not work properly, you just need to set the configuration for the jar-plugin like so:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...     
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <plugin>
    [Your shade plugin definition without the transformers here]
  </plugin> 
</build>
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget to add shade as a target:

`mvn clean package shade:shade`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10123988)

Comment: @MuhammadReda For me it was the solution for the exact same errors, possibly for the author too.

Comment: This one didn't work for me.  I still get the same error.

Comment: This was the solution too, I think being its own answer is good

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have more than one main().  If you do, maven needs to know which one to use.