# How to create a JAR file to create a large neverending file

Tags: java, jar, storage, space

I want to know how do I create a jar that will write to a .txt or generate a huge file once executed. It will either generate a huge file or keep writing to a file as fast as possible to *bloat up the storage*. The main point is to keep generating content or to take up the whole space of a storage. I am using this for my own purposes only.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi, I do not have any idea on how to do this. Can you teach me how to do this? Are there any sources that does this? I cant find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
try(PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)))) {

     while(true) {
           out.println("more text");
     }
}catch (IOException e) {
     //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

*Warning*: This will potentially write a huge file ;) - You can increase the amount by writing more bytes at a time. Simple insert a lager text.

Comment: Hi, I tried to run it but it displays no main manifest attribute. What do I do? Sorry!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute