# Extracted and recreated jar does not honor manifest at `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to figure out how to package a Jython program as a standalone runnable jar and I have run into a strange problem.

```
mkdir /tmp/stackoverflow
```

Get the Jython standalone jar somehow.

```
wget http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/python/jython-standalone/2.7.0/jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar && mv ./*.jar ./jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar
```

Observe that it runs a Jython repl when not passed a script as a command line argument.

```
java -jar ./jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar
```

Produces:

```
Jython 2.7.0 (default:9987c746f838, Apr 29 2015, 02:25:11) 
[OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_95
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I unpack the jar and repack it, it complains about a missing manifest.

```
mkdir unpack
cd unpack
jar -xf ../jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar
# repack jar
jar -cvf output.jar ./*
```

This time `java -jar output.jar` produces the following output

```
no main manifest attribute, in output.jar
```

As it turns out the contents of `output.jar` and `jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar` differ, but I think this this is just the nature of the beast when it comes to compression

```
$ diff output.jar ../jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar
Binary files output.jar and ../jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar differ
```

The paths contained within do not differ, however (the following command produces no output)

```
$ diff <(jar -tf ../jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar | sort) <(jar -tf output.jar | sort)
```

What the heck is going on? Why isn't the new jar honoring the `MANIFEST.MF` it contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the `jar` needs to be explicitly told where to look for the `MANIFEST.MF` file.

```
jar -cvmf META-INF/MANIFEST.MF output.jar ./* 

produces a jar that can be run just like the original one. This still leaves the question of what file actually changes when a `MANIFEST.MF` file is specified as an argument.
```

[Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute?rq=1)