# No main class in manifest with maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, manifest

I have my IntelliJ maven project and I am trying to build the jar but whenever I run it it throws `no main manifest attribute, in Project.jar`

Here is my pom.xml build. I am trying to set the main class in the manifest with Maven I read online to do it in the maven-compiler-plugin. When I open the jar in WinRar the manifest is generated by Apache Maven but has not got the main class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>

                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.bwfcwalshy.ssbbot.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure the compiler plugin can't do this (it compiles your code, doesn't produce the jar). You need to specify it in whatever packages your jar, probably maven-jar-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Add the maven-jar-plugin and make sure you use the maven directory structure (src/main/java) for your java files.

```
...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.bwfcwalshy.ssbbot.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```