# Fernflower and IntelliJ IDEA's java-decompiler

Tags: java, intellij-idea, decompiler

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [Fernflower](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower) Java decompiler.

I can find `java-decompiler.jar` at the following location:

```
~/idea-IC-162.1628.40/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar
```

There is no `fernflower.jar`, however. I assume this is because the functionality has been folded into `java-compiler.jar`, and the Fernflower README has simply not been updated in 2 years.

When I run the following, however:

```
java -jar ~/idea-IC-162.1628.40/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar myclassfile.class .
```

I get

> no main manifest attribute, in /home//idea-IC-162.1628.40/plugins/java-decompiler/lib/java-decompiler.jar

Has IntelliJ stopped supporting command-line based decompilation, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to invoke main class `org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler` manually

```
java -cp java-decompiler.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler myclassfile.class .
```

Also you can find more about internal usage of Fernflower inside IDEA by query in source code
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Fernflower

Comment: Great, this works. TIL about the difference between [executable and non-executable JARs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9689868/864684).

Comment: You can also decompile jar files and folders by passing them instead of a class file.

Comment: @JesusH Thanks, I try and worked. `java -cp java-decompiler.jar org.jetbrains.java.decompiler.main.decompiler.ConsoleDecompiler '.\org-demo-push-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' push`