# How to set classpath for a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I created a maven project with eclipse and made jar file from it with this below comand

**mvn package**

when i try to know my mvn project config is true or not with this command

**mvn exec:java -D exec.mainClass="giraph.helloworld.App"**

i get this error :

> failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java(default-cli) on project
>   helloworld: An exception occured while executing the java class. null:
>   InvocationTargetException: No arguments were provided

POM.xml setting of project is as follows. I will be so grateful if anyone can help me and specifies the reasons of this error?

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">  
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>giraph</groupId>   
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>  
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>   
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>helloworld</name>   
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>            
     </properties>

    <dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.giraph</groupId>
        <artifactId>giraph-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>    
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>    
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
        <version>2.0.2</version>    
    </dependency>       
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>    
   <dependency>     
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>  
    <version>2.10</version>
   </dependency>  
 </dependencies>
 <build> 
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
          </goals>
         <configuration>
           <mainClass>giraph.helloworld.App</mainClass>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build> 
</project>
```

Comment: How are you creating the manifest file for your project?

Comment: I add mainClass in POM file using exec-maven-plugin. I think POM file acts like a manifest . is it true?

Comment: POM is supposed to generate that but there are some things missing in your POM. Check this out - https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-manifest-file-with-maven/

Comment: Also, if you can, please post your manifest file

Comment: I dont see manifest file in my POM file. is it exist in my project?

Comment: If you are using maven on eclipse, the manifest file must be somewhere inside target folder

Comment: I think manifest file add into final jar file. one another question? is require to specify all of the dependencies to final executable jar file?

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to packaging all your dependencies (libraries) into your application jar. The answer is, yes you can. You can modify your POM file and add some plugins to create something called 'uber' jar. Maybe you can look into that.

Comment: i cant find manifest file inside target folder. may be mvn package command cant executes completely.

Comment: did you check the link the posted earlier ?

Comment: yes i checked it. i mounted jar file file and saw that manifest file is added into jar file. and has below texts.

Comment: Manifest-version: 1.0     Archive-version: plexus    archiver created by: Apache maven     Built by : erfan    build-jdk: 1.8.0_121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your manifest file does not contain information about the entry point (the main class) of your jar. See [Setting an Application entry point](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

There are many ways to rectify this problem. You can use maven assembly plugin. For more details, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)