# no main manifest attribute: intellij java ide

Tags: java, intellij-idea, manifest, manifest.mf

I am attempting to run an plugin for the itellij ide, the plugin consists of a jar file. However the file cannot open on my mac as it generates message "app could not be launched". Further reference to the console revealed the problem lay in "no main manifest attribute, in "app.jar"".

This question: [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute) is very similar. The solution asked to specify the MAIN-CLASS so I searched for a main in entire JAR and found nothing, which led me to come here and ask. Is there a certain line I need to add to the manifest file or path to set? Does Intellij not need a main-class line to be specified? Have linked the image below. Thanks!!!

[plugin's manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYxxT.png)

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA plugins are loaded by the IDE when placed into the [plugins directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519). They are not supposed to be run as Java applications (via `java -jar …`).

Comment: Ok will try placing into directory