# How to run RESTEasy project

Tags: java, maven, resteasy

I have trying to learn RESTEasy using this repo:

https://github.com/dashorst/jaxrs-quickstart-resteasy

After cloning it, i run `mvn clean package`, and then I have tried

`cd target` and `java -jar resteasy-quickstart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
I got this error:

`no main manifest attribute, in resteasy-quickstart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

I also tried directly run the test code in

`cd target/test-classes`

And run `java Start`, but I got this error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I am not using eclipse or intellij, I just want to launch the server from command line and visit the site from browser. I have searched several similar questions like [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute) but none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy `resteasy-quickstart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` file into an running application server.

For example, you could start Jetty and copy the file .war into the `webapps` directory.

### Step 1

Here how to download the Jetty server: 
https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html

### Step 2

After uncompressing the archive (zip or tar.gz), open a shell, enter the Jetty home and run:

```
./bin/jetty.sh start
```

You'll see the Jetty through the url

http://localhost:8080/

### Step 3

Then copy your .war file into `./webapps` directory

Your project will be available following the url

http://localhost:8080/resteasy-quickstart-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/