# fail to execute jar file in linux

Tags: java, linux, jar

I had developed a standalone program which don't have any GUI, it's only use in the linux machine(without any GUI). So, i converted my java source code into jar file using the following command

```
jar cfm hardcoded.jar manifest.txt hardcoded.class
```

The jar file was successfully created but when i try to execute the jar file in the terminal,i get this error

```
no main manifest attribute, in hardcoded.jar
```

Some of the information said that the problem due to the manifest file but i can't figure out where is the root cause because i am very new to java on linux,Some people said that the package also need to include but where can i find my package name?.My manifest file is showed as the following

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ./ commons-logging-1.1.2.jar httpclient-4.5.2.jar htt
 pcore-4.4.1.jar java-json.jar java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar javax-ssl-1
 _1.jar joda-time-2.2.jar
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: hardcoded
```

As you can see my manifest file, i had some others external library, i know eclipse have the build in function to solve this issue, how i need to solve it in linux environment ?

Comment: Are you using all of those dependencies? If so, I would recommend maven to manage them. If not, know that is not how you add jars (or manipulate the class-path).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , yes, i need all those library but there's will only one class file

Comment: Can you try `java -cp hardcoded.jar hardcoded` and see what happens?

Comment: The JRE may may not like the class been in the root/default pacakge

Comment: You should get a good solution in this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute

Comment: @DatHuynh, it's show me this error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/TrustStrategy
"

Comment: @UdaraGunathilake, that is the solution i had refer before but can't hundred percent get what they mean, this is my first time using text editor to develop java,i used eclipse before this

Comment: Does your `hardcoded` class have a package name?

Comment: @DatHuynh, no any package name

Comment: In your manifest file, make sure your `Class-Path`s are right, it seems like it's messed up somehow (hence the `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/ssl/TrustStrategy`). Maybe try full paths?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, can you explain it more detail ?

Comment: @DatHuynh, i added in the full path for my library file,it's still look the same, please refer to this link (http://codepad.org/lzSTcB5B) for my new updated manifest