# Google's pepk-src not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to follow the instructions on the Google Developer's Console to retrieve my .pem certificate's private key to use with the Google Play App Signing. Since I'm not using a Java keystore, I tried the advanced instructions, but on executing the file, I get `no main manifest attribute, in pepk-src.jar` error. What gives? I'm using `java version "1.8.0_101"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute

Comment: Tried those, didn't work. Kind of weird that it doesn't run properly when it's part of their instructions -__-

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have te same issue

Comment: same here..doesn't anyone have answer to this question?

Comment: same problem here. It's completely unclear how to user this file

Comment: The pepk-src.jar is the source code of PEPK. You can use it to look how Play encrypts the key, so you can perform the same operation if your key is not in a Java Keystore. There are no detailed instructions for this use-case because each developer would have different ways to extract their private key.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The download link they gave is apparently a source jar file, maybe they did that accidentally.

Screenshot from Google Play Console showing the "source" jar file link:
[image: Screenshot from Google Play Console showing the "source" jar file link ("pepk-src.jar")]

Try to use this jar file (from Google): https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar

Screenshot from Google Play Console showing the jar file link ("pepk.jar")

[image: Screenshot from Google Play Console showing the jar file link ("pepk.jar")]

Good luck, peace out!

Comment: Wish I could do this answer justice, but I've long left the place where I had this problem. If someone else tries this and it works for them, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: I just experienced this problem (Google still hasn't fix their website!) and I can confirm - this answer absolutely works.

Comment: That's a good answer. Look for gstatic.com in [link](https://lookup.icann.org/lookup) to see that this domain belongs to Google...

Comment: 4 years and this is still not fixed on google's page.

Comment: Almost 5 years. There must be so many other more important bugs to fix that nobody finds the time to correct this ... or is it intention ("if these developers are not able to recognize and run a Java source file they should stop developing")

Comment: Its 2023, its still not fixed. :(