# Unable to run jar file getting "Error: Could not find or load main class com.trident.SchedulerMain"

Tags: java, maven, jar

I know this is duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute) and so many other. But after trying all the solutions, i am still facing this issue.

Here is my `pom.xml`.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.trident.optimize</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.3.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <springsecurity.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>6.0.5</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON dependencies -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jcifs/jcifs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.opencsv/opencsv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- HTTPClient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
            <version>40.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-partner-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>force-partner-api</artifactId>
            <version>40.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.trident.SchedulerMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And `mvn` version is:

> `Apache Maven 3.3.9
>    Maven home: /usr/share/maven
>    Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>    Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>    Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
>    OS name: "linux", version: "4.10.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: 
>    "unix"`

And i am using following commands to run jar file

- `java -jar xyz.jar`
  and getting error:`no main manifest attribute, in xyz.jar`
- `java -cp xyz.jar com.trident.SchedulerMain` and getting error:`Error: Could not find or load main class com.trident.SchedulerMain`

Even tried creating `MANIFEST.MF` and added these lines

`Main-Class: com.trident.SchedulerMain`

But still no luck. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: unzip the jar file, what is the correct class path? Did you forget the `optimze` package that is part of the groupId?

Answer (score 0):

pls ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. if your .class file is in the current folder then add . to your classpath. If your class is in a package then call `java -classpath . packagename.ClassName`

Comment: Where should i have to provide it? in `MANIFEST.MF` file or while running jar?