# I cannot install MySQL JDBC driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: jdbc, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-connector, manifest.mf

I downloaded the MySQL JDBC driver to connect Scala to a MySQL database, but I cannot install it with `java -jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar`. It says, **no main manifest attribute, in mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar**

I cannot find any MANIFEST.MF file.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: warnings after I run `sbt run`

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/alessandro/Scala/tests/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to MyProject (in build file:/home/alessandro/Scala/tests/)
[info] Running tests.ScalaJdbcConnectSelect 
Sun Feb 18 21:51:33 CET 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'pmanager.user' doesn't exist
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2480)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2438)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1381)
    at tests.ScalaJdbcConnectSelect$.delayedEndpoint$tests$ScalaJdbcConnectSelect$1(ScalaJdbcConnectSelect.scala:16)
    at tests.ScalaJdbcConnectSelect$delayedInit$body.apply(ScalaJdbcConnectSelect.scala:5)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at tests.ScalaJdbcConnectSelect$.main(ScalaJdbcConnectSelect.scala:5)
    at tests.ScalaJdbcConnectSelect.main(ScalaJdbcConnectSelect.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:93)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:87)
    at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:65)
    at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:77)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[success] Total time: 3 s, completed Feb 18, 2018, 9:51:34 PM
```

Comment: The question was asked previously : [Can't execute jar- file: “no main manifest attribute”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Where does it say you should execute the jar file to install it? You just have to add it to your *project* and its CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I found two options:

***The first***

In your `build.sbt` replace line

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24"
```

with this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.16"
)
```

In command line:

```
sbt compile
sbt run
```

***The second***

Use this in command line:

```
set fullClasspath in Compile += Attributed.blank(file("path-to-your-connector-jar"))
sbt compile
sbt run
```

After that, the problem with the driver should disappear, but check the data to connect to the database.

**BEFORE UPDATE:**

In your project on Scala you also can use this:

```
package tests

import java.sql.{Connection,DriverManager}

object ScalaJdbcConnectSelect extends App {

  // connect to the database named "mysql" on port 8889 of localhost
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mysql"
  val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  val username = "root"
  val password = "root"
  var connection:Connection = _
  try {
    Class.forName(driver)
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
    val statement = connection.createStatement
    val rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT host, user FROM user")
    while (rs.next) {
      val host = rs.getString("host")
      val user = rs.getString("user")
      println("host = %s, user = %s".format(host,user))
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
  }
  connection.close
}
```

[Link to source 1](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch16s02.html)

[Link to source 2](http://qaru.site/questions/286823/add-toolsjar-in-the-classpath-of-sbt-project)

Comment: Shouldn't I install the JDBC driver on my system, before I can use it in my code? All I have now is the .jar file.

Comment: @A.N.Other add this jar to `classpath` in project.

Comment: The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been necessary since 2007.

Comment: I've done that, but it says "No such file or class on classpath: ScalaJdbcConnectSelect" when I type scala ScalaJdbcConnectSelect

Comment: @A.N.Other you must add this jar to your `classpath` in project. As here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJhLT.png in WEB-INF/classes/lib

Comment: I've done that, but I am not using maven, in my build.sbt file there is the info:
name := "MyProject"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.24" but when I run sbt run there are a lot of error messages

Comment: I am editing my original question with them, thanks.

Comment: @A.N.Other are these all messages?

Comment: There are others before but they don't seem actual errors, some sort of warnings. And then others I had to cut because body is limited to 3000 charachters. I followed the turorials from https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-connect-mysql-database-scala-jdbc-select-query

Comment: @A.N.Other OK, what IDE do you use?

Comment: I am not using any IDE, because I wanted to learn the basics of Scala compiling, etc. I copied the script from the link, and saved it with nano, I adapted it to my MySQL user name, password and database name. I have a command-line based MySQL database.

Comment: Hello, thanks, I am not getting error messages after the update, but on the other side it doesn't print what it should print after sbt run

Comment: @A.N.Other check your database port, database name, tables and other info. I'm not see what you have (database, your script).

Comment: @A.N.Other If the problem with JDBC is solved, you can close the question.

Comment: I am getting a lot of warnings tough, is it normal?

Comment: @A.N.Other you can use online services for this. https://codeshare.io for example

Comment: I updated the original question with the new warnings after your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this line:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'pmanager.user' doesn't exist
```

Check if there is such a table. If so, leave characters after the point (`user`).

Comment: I just noticed that, but in the scala script there is no table info to be written, it is asking only for user, password and database name. Am I missing something?

Comment: @A.N.Other Somewhere in script you have `pmanager.user` or only `user`. Find this, check and replace.

Comment: @A.N.Other also I'm not see the script. Maybe I can help you if you'll show it

Comment: Here is the script: 

https://codeshare.io/Gkw9rA

Database name is pmanager and there is only one table, parchive.

Comment: Look at this: `val rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT host, user FROM pmanager")`. Here must be not `parchive` - your database name. Here must be table name. Try with `parchive`.

Comment: Done. I also had to correct the two fields names, too. Now it works OK. Thank you so much.

Comment: @A.N.Other awesome!

Comment: I am a beginner in Scala and MySQL so forgive me, thanks a lot again.

Comment: I really couldn't do all this without help.

Comment: @A.N.Other sure, this place for questions and answers :) (I don't not use Scala at all)