# JavaFX Application : launching by double click?

Tags: java, javafx, app-launcher

I have created a JavaFX application in order to register data on my personal computer (Windows 10)  and I am looking for launching it by double clicking on its JAR.

thank you in advance for your help.

Vinz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: Thank you for the link Nevertheless, I tried the operations which are on this page but it has not worked.

Comment: What does "has not worked" mean - what actually happens? If you run the jar file from the command line, do you see any exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

well i had the same problem after i was taught to use  JAVAFX a week ago we had to use command line but that led to an idea

```
java -jar --module-path "C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml yourjarfile.jar
```

type above in notepad and save it as a batch file (.cmd) launch the batch file

> or shall i say double click!!!

Comment: Good solution. Thx. It could be solved as: `java -jar --module-path %cd%\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml yourjarfile.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a launcher. It would give you many options like minimum and maximum 
 supported JRE versions, heap size, and error messages' alerts. Take a look at [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: does it work for javaFX? JavaFX is not part of the JDK anymore ( non JAVA FX program runs fine on double click without using the batch file i am suggesting)

Answer (score 0):

This is all not the way it is done today. Just use jpackage, which comes with JDK 14, and build a real application or installer with it. Then you can not only double click to launch your application, you will also benefit from all the other goodies like icons, install/uninstall, desktop integration, ... Have a look here to see how it works: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX