# Can you set main manifest without manually editing pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven

It seems even when you use maven archetypes like [maven-archetype-quickstart](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) or [maven-archetype-simple](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-simple/), setting the `mainClass` manifest seems to be still something one has to do manually. However, going to [the Q&A that provides the necessary POM entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute) and copy-pasting it seems inefficient. Is there some maven command or some other tool to set it? Or is there some archetype that already contains this entry?

Comment: You could create your own archetype. You can set up a project with the necessary configuration and generate an archetype from it.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if that’s even a good idea, since the quickstart archetype notably omits it although it contains a class with a main function.

Comment: Does that really makes sense cause usually in each project the main class is different?   Isn't it?

Comment: @khmarbaise I wouldn’t even mind manually editing pom.xml, if it’s just the name of the class. (whenever I want to name the class not "App" as in the archetype) I just don’t like typing in the whole tree for "maven-jar-plugin" plugin.