# Java -jar not working with customised folder name (cloud) in place of default lib

Tags: java, cmd, jar

**Java -jar OracleOCISecondary.jar param1 param2**

> I am trying to run a jar file using the command prompt having some dependency jars.

While running it using default generated lib folder and manifest file it is working fine but when I change the lib folder name to oracle and same in the MANIFEST.MF file, it is saying as below :

> *no main manifest attribute, in OracleOCISecondary.jar*

Here is my manifest.mf file :-

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
  Created-By: 1.8.0_66-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
  Class-Path: oracle/oracle-1.0.jar oracle/Util-1.0.jar oracle/aopalliance-repacka
   ged-2.5.0-b05.jar oracle/apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar oracle/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.52
   .jar oracle/bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar oracle/commons-codec-1.10.jar oracle/commo
   ns-io-2.1.jar oracle/commons-lang3-3.4.jar oracle/guava-19.0.jar oracle/hk2-ap
   i-2.5.0-b05.jar oracle/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b05.jar oracle/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b05
   .jar oracle/httpclient-4.5.2.jar oracle/httpcore-4.4.9.jar oracle/httpmime-4.0
   .1.jar oracle/jackson-annotations-2.7.4.jar oracle/jackson-core-2.7.4.jar 
   oracle/jackson-databind-2.7.4.jar oracle/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.7.4.jar oracle
   /jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.7.4.jar oracle/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.7.4.jar 
   oracle/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.7.4.jar oracle/jackson-module-jaxb-anno
   tations-2.7.4.jar oracle/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar oracle/javax.annotation-ap
   i-1.2.jar oracle/javax.inject-2.5.0-b05.jar oracle/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.ja
   r oracle/jersey-client-2.24.1.jar oracle/jersey-common-2.24.1.jar oracle/jerse
   y-guava-2.24.1.jar oracle/jsr305-3.0.1.jar oracle/log4j-1.2.16.jar oracle/oci-
   java-sdk-full-1.2.27.jar oracle/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar oracle/slf4
   j-api-1.7.21.jar oracle/tomitribe-http-signatures-1.0.jar oracle/validation
   -api-1.1.0.Final.jar
  X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
  Main-Class: com.corenttech.engine.secondary.oracle.OracleOciOperations
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that your file contains a new line or a carriage return at the end. See [Java SE docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) or [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28134909/3714983).