# Create executable JAR using mvn package and run JUnit tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, jar

I am trying to package my code into a single executable JAR and then run the tests from the JAR. When I run

`mvn package`

and then

`java -jar -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:~/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar:. elevator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar cscie55.hw3.elevator.ElevatorTest`

I get an error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class elevator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

If I run just

`java -jar elevator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I get an error saying `no main manifest attribute, in target/elevator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

I then tried following the advice in [Can't execute jar- file: “no main manifest attribute”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

But none of my classes or tests have a main method. I'm using `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` as the main method, to just run the tests.

I tried adding it as the main class in the maven-jar-plugin configuration:

```
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.junit.runner.JUnitCore</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But got an error stating:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

I also tried creating a TestRunner class that has a main method:

```
public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore.main("introtojava.hw3.elevator.ElevatorTest", "introtojava.hw3.zoo.animals.AnimalsTest");
    }
}
```

But I received a similar error message.

I tried using the maven-assembly-plugin as suggested in the link above, with the same results.

Completely out of ideas.

My project structure:

```
├── Projects.iml
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── introtojava
    │           └── hw3
    │               ├── elevator
    │               │   ├── Building.java
    │               │   ├── Elevator.java
    │               │   ├── ElevatorFullException.java
    │               │   ├── Floor.java
    │               │   └── Passenger.java
    │               └── zoo
    │                   ├── animals
    │                   │   ├── Animal.java
    │                   │   ├── Elephant.java
    │                   │   ├── Hippopotamus.java
    │                   │   ├── Rhinoceros.java
    │                   │   ├── Tiger.java
    │                   │   └── Zebra.java
    │                   └── iface
    │                       ├── Eatable.java
    │                       ├── Playable.java
    │                       └── Speakable.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── introtojava
                └── hw3
                    ├── TestRunner.java
                    ├── elevator
                    │   └── ElevatorTest.java
                    └── zoo
                        └── animals
                            └── AnimalsTest.java
```

Relevant bit of my pom.xml file:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${basedir}/target/classes/src
                            </outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/src</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to package into a jar and running the tests there instead using the mechanisms which already exists and name the tests accordingly and let Maven run them via `mvn clean test`?

Comment: It's a school assignment. They want me to submit it with the tests included, and they will run the tests directly from the jar file. They've included instructions on how to do it manually from the command line, but there's quite a few steps, and I want to just run `mvn package`. I could write a bash script, but I figured I'd prefer to have maven do it all for me.