# java -jar command is not working, no main manifest attribute

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I m new to java and trying to learn about jar. I have created simple HelloWorld program.
Created a jar file and trying to execute that jar.

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }

}
```

**Manifest.txt**

```
Main-Class: HelloWorld
```

Following command to create jar

```
jar cfm HelloWorld.jar Manifest.txt HelloWorld.class
```

So far so good, when I m trying execute jar its showing below message

```
E:\Java_Example>java -jar HelloWorld.jar
no main manifest attribute, in HelloWorld.jar
```

However, when I did google about it, I found another command which works fine for me.

```
E:\Java_Example>java -cp HelloWorld.jar HelloWorld
Hello, World
```

I need to understand why "java -jar" command did not work for me?
What changes I need to make to my program so that *java -jar* command will work?

Comment: What *package* is the main class present in?

Comment: And does your manifest file have a line-feed after the `Main-Class: HelloWorld` statement? It should.

Comment: I'm not using any package.. HelloWorld.java code is exactly same what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but you should avoid using the "default" package

Comment: Got the answer, there was no line-feed after the Main-Class: HelloWorld, you can post this as answer I will accept it. Thanks :)

Comment: No need for me to post an answer -- it was one of the answers in the "possible duplicate" that I already posted in my first (now deleted) comment.

Comment: Note for future reference that the duplicate was not hard to find by searching this site for similar questions

Comment: Also, you'll want to up-vote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28134909/522444)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Upvoted :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Only thing is, if compiler is not able to find parse the manifest file or find the main class name, then shouldnt it throw an error ? I just put some random values in manifest file and tried to create a jar and it did not throw an error.

Comment: I suppose that it would be nice if it did, but there you have it