# No main manifest attribute, in service.jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to deploy my springboot application on a docker.
I have created a docker file as follows.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir /app
COPY Service.jar /app/Service.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/Service.jar"]
```

The dockerfile builds fine but when I run the image it throws the following error:
`no main manifest attribute, in /app/Service.jar`

Service is a java springboot application and has rest endpoints. using gradle as a build tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: my META-INF contains a context.xml which has only one tag

Comment: You should be using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (assuming you are using maven) to build the jar. If you don't you are missing crucial information, amongst others the properly prepared `MANIFEST.MF` in the `META-INF` directory.