# Run Main class of base docker image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot application which contains a Main Class. I have Docker File as below:

```
FROM docker.io/openjdk:11-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8082
EXPOSE 8443
ADD target/base-application.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar /app.jar
```

I am creating a Docker image by using this Docker file. Let's consider that this docker file is Docker1.

I have another Spring Boot application (which doesn't have a Main class) with Docker file as below:

```
FROM Docker1:0.0.1
EXPOSE 8443
ADD target/child-application.jar app.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar /app.jar
```

I am using Docker1 as a base image for the docker image of 2nd application. When I am trying to run 2nd docker image, I am getting an error "no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar". Can you please help me to run the Main class of Docker1 by running 2nd Docker image?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried the solutions related at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute ?

Comment: In the second image, `/app.jar` is the jar file from the second stage, which as you say doesn't have a main class.  The jar file from the first stage is overwritten by the second stage's `ADD` instruction.

Comment: @SandroAthaide, I had already done the changes given on that link. The only part that I was missing is in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to run main class from target/base-application.jar file. Below line in Docker2 replaces base-application.jar with child-application.jar

```
ADD target/child-application.jar app.jar
```

To fix the issue you can modify your second Docker file as:

```
FROM Docker1:0.0.1
EXPOSE 8443
ADD target/child-application.jar child-application.jar
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar /app.jar
```