# 'Application Error' when Im deploying one of my services on Heroku

Tags: java, windows, rest, heroku, deployment

There is a problem that I really need help to solve it.
I have no much experience with using Heroku, but I use to deploy a few apps successfully. Now after deploying is succeed I try to launch the app in my browser and get this Error:

> ```
> Application error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
> heroku logs --tail
> ```

I attached below the logs I checked in my Heroku CLI, but I still don't understand what exact the problem in my application java code. Is any ideas or own experience with it? Thanks

**THE LOGS I GOT**

[image]

Comment: Avoid sharing logs as snapshots, paste the logs instead and format them appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the text of your error:
"`no main manifest attribute, in target /ProPetsAccountingService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`"

Pay attention to the answers to this question:
[Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Or check what is listed in your "Procfile".

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really problem with this annotation: just forgot put it to one of the configuration classes. It solved the problem