# Source code compilation failed with Docker and maven and settings.xml

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

Getting source code compilation failuer error with below docker file.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS base
EXPOSE 8080:8080
FROM maven:3.6.0-ibmjava-8 AS build
WORKDIR /mywrkdir
COPY src src
COPY pom.xml .
COPY settings.xml .
RUN mvn -s settings.xml clean package
FROM base AS final
COPY --from=build /mywrkdir/target/xxx.jar xxx.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=someEnvironmentVariable","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","xxx.jar"]
```

There is settings.xml with some specific profiles and repositories needed for application to build. For that purpose used maven command. But at below stage getting compilation error.

```
RUN mvn -s settings.xml clean package
```

Command used to build the test image is as below

```
az acr build --registry MyAcr --image testimg .
```

Error log when building docker file . Nothing is getting compiled RUN mvn stage from dockerfile:

```
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 31 source files to /xxx /target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/.java:[10,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/..java:[11,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/..java:[12,52] package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/..java:[13,38] package org.springframework.stereotype does not exis
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/.java:[21,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class Service
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/.java:[24,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Logger
  location: class 
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/.java:[3,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
[ERROR] /xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxx/.java:[4,17] package org.slf4j does not exist
.
.
.
…….
[INFO] 100 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  06:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project xxxx: Compilation failure: Compilation failure
```

Comment: what error do you get when building Doecker file ?

Comment: Cedric, getting compilation error as attached in original question.

Comment: I get the error mentioned in original question during building Docker file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, try copying the entire directory, maybe you are missing some required file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine AS base
EXPOSE 8080:8080
FROM maven:3.6.0-ibmjava-8 AS build
WORKDIR /mywrkdir
COPY ./ . # <-------- CHANGE MADE HERE
RUN mvn -s settings.xml clean package
FROM base AS final
COPY --from=build /mywrkdir/target/xxx.jar xxx.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=someEnvironmentVariable","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","xxx.jar"]
```

Comment: Tried this, now that compilation error is gone. But getting **no main manifest attribute, in ./xx.jar** error message when trying to run via docker run command

Comment: Try referring on answer of this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute) to solve your issue