# Run old java mobile game (Castlevania Dawn of sorrow)

Tags: java, mobile

I am trying to run an old game (Castlevania, dawn of sorrow) which I had on my Cellphone and found on this page.
(http://www.mobyware.org/java-os/role-games-tag/castlevania-dawn-of-sorrow-download-220618.html)

When I run the following command on the terminal
$ java -jar castlevani_220618.jar

I get the following error
no main manifest attribute, in castlevani_220618.jar

I have been looking for an answer online, but since I am new with Java I am kind of lost.

I saw this post, but I do not really understand it :(
[Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look here for an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)