# no main manifest attribute, in target/Dayo_Management-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

I try deploy and run my SpringBoot api. When I use below dependesse I can deploy but no run:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

This is the erro when i run `heroku logs --tail` late deploy:

```
2022-06-05T01:50:47.814041+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2022-06-05T01:50:47.831399+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2022-06-05T01:50:47.836773+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2022-06-05T01:50:47.908417+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/Dayo_Management-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2022-06-05T01:50:48.024671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-05T01:50:48.077280+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-05T01:51:01.078855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dayo-management.herokuapp.com request_id=e145401e-54c3-4d9c-b734-cea5d9bded39 fwd="179.67.129.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-05T01:51:01.887771+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dayo-management.herokuapp.com request_id=1281e5e4-3275-4697-b260-efd74fbf86c7 fwd="179.67.129.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-05T01:51:11.771681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/cliente/1" host=dayo-management.herokuapp.com request_id=87081e8a-af72-4f3f-ba25-5eff0bb86eee fwd="179.67.129.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-05T01:51:12.458742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dayo-management.herokuapp.com request_id=9a6bdfb1-b4af-4232-8026-58369ce22df9 fwd="179.67.129.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-05T01:54:10.923517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/clientes/1" host=dayo-management.herokuapp.com request_id=da9428d4-c911-4032-8903-22414708da58 fwd="179.67.129.0" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I try a lot of types to my file pom.xml but nothing works.

[Here is my GitHub repository](https://github.com/thiagomota456/Dayo-Maneger)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: I read this awswer. Don't work for me