# CrashLoopBackOff when deploying Sample Spring Boot K8s on Minikube using Helm

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kotlin, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Am new to Docker, K8s, and Helm...

Was following an online [tutorial](https://dev.to/gateixeira/deploying-a-spring-boot-kotlin-app-on-kubernetes-with-docker-and-helm-589p) to learn how to deploy a basic Kotlin Spring Boot Microservice onto `minikube` using `Helm Charts`.

Project structure:

```
demo-spring-boot
│
├── Dockerfile
├── HELP.md
├── README.md
├── build.gradle
├── charts
│   ├── Chart.yaml
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── deployment.yaml
│   │   └── service.yaml
│   └── values.yaml
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── kotlin
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── demo
    │   │           ├── HelloController.kt
    │   │           └── DemoApplication.kt
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       ├── static
    │       └── templates
    └── test
        └── kotlin
            └── com
                └── demo
                    └── DemoApplicationTests.kt
```

---

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

---

`build.gradle`:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.22'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.7.22'
}

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

`charts/Charts.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: helm
description: "A Helm chart for our demo-spring-boot application"
type: application
version: 0.1.0
appVersion: latest
```

---

`charts/values.yaml`:

```
appName: demo-spring-boot
namespace: default
appVersion: latest
replicaCount: 1
image:
  registry: demo
  pullPolicy: Never
```

---

`templates/deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  name: {{ .Values.appName }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.appName }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.appName }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.appName }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "{{ .Values.appName }}"
          image: "{{ .Values.image.registry }}/{{ .Values.appName }}:{{ .Values.appVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}"
      restartPolicy: Always
```

---

`templates/service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  name: {{ .Values.appName }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.appName }}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 172.16.0.1
  sessionAffinity: None
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: {{ .Values.appName }}
```

---

`HelloController.kt`:

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun hello(): String {
        return "Hello World!"
    }

}
```

---

Whereas, I can run this via `localhost` and see `Hello World!` in my browser, I keep getting a `CrashLoopBackOff` error which is causing a bunch of restarts via `minikube`.

So, the steps I followed:

1. Started `minikube`:

`minikube start --memory 2048 --cpus 2 --disk-size 10g`

Output in `stdout`:

```
  minikube v1.30.1 on Darwin 12.6.4
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
❗  You cannot change the memory size for an existing minikube cluster. Please first delete the cluster.
❗  You cannot change the disk size for an existing minikube cluster. Please first delete the cluster.
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Updating the running docker "minikube" container ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.26.3 on Docker 23.0.2 ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

2. `eval $(minikube docker-env)`:

This doesn't return anything in `stdout`

3. Built the docker image using:

`docker build -t gateixeira/demo-spring-boot:latest .`

4. Deployed using `helm`:

```
helm upgrade --install demo-spring-boot charts --values charts/values.yaml                                               INT kube minikube
```

5. When I check pods:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
demo-spring-boot-6965d67897-wkcns   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   8 (4m43s ago)   20m
```

---

When trying to troubleshoot by inspecting the logs:

`kubectl logs demo-spring-boot-6965d67897-wkcns --all-containers`

Response in `stdout`:

`no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar`

Would appreciate it if someone could show me some troubleshooting steps...

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this Gradle settings,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9689877/13939499, this doesn't looks like a helm or k8s error, but more of Gradle-java **jar** packaging type.