# Can't execute .jar file compiled by NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Java, I made a simple code, with a .java file and a .form file and when I try to export to .jar, clicking on build, the file can't be executed.

When I try to execute:

```
xpray@xpray:~/.m2/repository/com/couple/1.0$ java -jar couple-1.0
Error: Unable to access jarfile couple-1.0
xpray@xpray:~/.m2/repository/com/couple/1.0$ java -jar couple-1.0.jar
no main manifest attribute, in couple-1.0.jar
```

Can anyone help me? I'm sorry if it's too basic.

Edit: I know there are similar issues here, the problem is that I don't know anything about it, I have no idea how to edit the MANIFEST. MF, and in theory, wasn't it supposed to work after building NetBeans?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: Can you share the content of the jar file? Unzip it and post the contents here.