# no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar / gradle.kts/sprinboot

Tags: docker, attributes, manifest, gradle-kotlin-dsl

when i am run docker run  myorg/myapp - i got error

no main manifest attribute, in /app.jar, i searching the answer in this [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

but nothing works for me..

this is gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"

}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5")
    implementation ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.22.0")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.3.0")
    implementation("org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.3.0")




    //developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.1")
    testImplementation("org.mockito:mockito-core:5.8.0")

}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()


}

tasks.withType<Jar>() {

    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = "com.example.effectiveMoblile.EffectiveMoblileApplication"
    }
    configurations["compileClasspath"].forEach { file: File ->
        from(zipTree(file.absoluteFile))
    }
}
```

this is my docker file

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

CMD ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar /app.jar ${0} ${@}"]
```

in jar file manifest.mf have next text

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: build.libs.effectiveMoblile-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-plain
Start-Class: com.example.effectiveMoblile.EffectiveMoblileApplication
Spring-Boot-Version: 3.2.0
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
Build-Jdk-Spec: 17
Implementation-Title: effectiveMoblile
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

i don't understand what i can do, that work....

i searching the answer in this [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your setup.

1. The copy you're doing is faulty, you are copying any `target/*.jar` to `app.jar`, but you should be specific, otherwise if there are multiple jar files, the behavior will be inconsistent.
2. (and the reason for failing) You're using Kotlin, which appends **Kt** to your class names, so instead of "EffectiveMoblileApplication", it should be EffectiveMoblileApplication**Kt**. (i.e. `com.example.effectiveMoblile.EffectiveMoblileApplicationKt`)

As a side note, I don't recommend writing the `manifest.mf` file, but instead use the [shadow jar](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/) plugin.

To do so:

- delete the manifest you've created
- add the following to your Gradle file:

```
plugins {
  // rest of the plugins
  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
}

// will rename the resulting package
tasks.withType<ShadowJar> {
    archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
}
```

This way, you will also be able to do the copy as `COPY target/app.jar app.jar`, in case you're performing `target/*.jar` due to Gradle appending the version.