# How does org.apache.maven.indexer:indexer-cli:7.1.1 work?

Tags: java, maven, java-11, maven-indexer

I'm tying to create an Maven index for my private project and I'm tying to use **org.apache.maven.indexer:indexer-cli:7.1.1** to do so. However, when calling the jar all I get is an error message:

```
>  java -jar /…/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar  \ 
        --repository    "${HOMEPAGE_DEPLOY}"                                    \
        --index         "${HOMEPAGE_DEPLOY}/.index"                             \
        --destination   "${HOMEPAGE_DEPLOY}/.index"                             \
        --name          "${PROJECT_NAME}"
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in /…/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar
```

Yes, all pathnames have been checked and a simplified call doesn't work as well:

```
>pushd /…/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/
>java -jar indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar 
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar
```

The only [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/repository/central-index.html) I found uses `java -jar` as well but that was for version 5.1.1 so I wonder if something changed.

I know about the nexus indexer but that one has stopped working after I moved to Java 11 and I don't want to be stuck with Java 8 forever. (They should have called Java 9 **Java 2.0** as it's a mayor and incompatible upgrade)

**Update 1:**

For completeness sake I did try **org.apache.maven.indexer:indexer-cli:5.1.1** and that actually works as expected. As does **org.apache.maven.indexer:indexer-cli:6.2.2** but not **org.apache.maven.indexer:indexer-cli:7.0.4**.

So it's change for Version 7.

**Update 2:**

After @khmarbaise question I decided to check the content of the the Jar-file. The file content looks ok and a MANIFEST.MF is present.

```
>7z l /…/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar

7-Zip [64] 17.05 : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2017-08-28
p7zip Version 17.05 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,16 CPUs x64)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 22886 bytes (23 KiB)                                                

Listing archive: /…/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar

--
Path = /…/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar
Type = zip
Physical Size = 22886

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  META-INF
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....          336          171  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  META-INF/sisu
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  org
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  org/apache
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  org/apache/maven
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  org/apache/maven/index
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  org/apache/maven/index/cli
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  META-INF/maven
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven.indexer
2023-12-13 22:35:30 D....            0            0  META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven.indexer/indexer-cli
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....         6190         1331  META-INF/DEPENDENCIES
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....        11358         3949  META-INF/LICENSE
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....          175          130  META-INF/NOTICE
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....           38           40  META-INF/sisu/javax.inject.Named
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....          732          403  org/apache/maven/index/cli/Components.class
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....         1016          516  org/apache/maven/index/cli/NexusIndexerCli$1.class
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....         4316         2051  org/apache/maven/index/cli/NexusIndexerCli$IndexerListener.class
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....        17445         8267  org/apache/maven/index/cli/NexusIndexerCli.class
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....         2093          951  org/apache/maven/index/cli/PartialImplementation.class
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....         6685         1917  META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven.indexer/indexer-cli/pom.xml
2023-12-13 22:35:30 .....           70           66  META-INF/maven/org.apache.maven.indexer/indexer-cli/pom.properties
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2023-12-13 22:35:30              50454        19792  12 files, 10 folders
```

I checked the sha1 checksum as well and is matches as well. Lastly I checked the `MANIFEST.MF` which is indeed missing the the `Main-Class:` entry:

```
>cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.3.0
Build-Jdk-Spec: 21
Specification-Title: Maven :: Indexer CLI
Specification-Version: 7.1
Specification-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
Implementation-Title: Maven :: Indexer CLI
Implementation-Version: 7.1.1
Implementation-Vendor: The Apache Software Foundation
```

Why did it work for @khmarbaise with a missing `Main-Class:` in the `MANIFEST.MF`?

**Update 3:**

Installed java 21 and tried again. Same result for Oracle Java and openjdk:

```
>JDK_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home \
>JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home \
>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar

>JDK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home \
>JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home \
>/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar
kein Hauptmanifestattribut, in indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute jar- file: "no main manifest attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689793/cant-execute-jar-file-no-main-manifest-attribute)

Comment: I downloaded https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar and `java -jar indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar` and it produced an output... `Use either unpack ("u") or index ("i" and "r") options, but none has been found!`... which means it will execute the jar... I would check if the downloaded jar is correctly downloaded ... check with SHA1...

Comment: @khmarbaise I checked the jar file as you suggested. See my updates. The `Main-Class:` in the `MANIFEST.MF` is missing. Why did it work for you? It should have failed. (I have a suspicion: `Build-Jdk-Spec: 21`)

Comment: @Martin I didn't downvote. Your question was unclear before editing that you already knew the error meaning and were asking for the _why_ in this specific JAR.

Comment: The build spec only tells you by which JDK the jar file has been created with... NOT which is required to run it.. apart from that if the jar required JDK 21 to run the error message would have looked different (`has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0`)... Have you downloaded that file form central repository (link given in my previous comment) ? That looks strange because my (MANFIFEST.MF) file contains correctly main class entry as well `Multi-Release: true`...

Comment: Ah now the issue is clear. You have to use this file: `indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar`. and NOT `indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar`...You are using the wrong file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question (again). With Version 7 and onwards the file structure of **indexer-cli** package has changed. For comparison:

### [Version 6.2.2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/6.2.2/):

```
org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/6.2.2
../
indexer-cli-6.2.2-javadoc.jar                     2022-07-16 15:47    136897      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-javadoc.jar.asc                 2022-07-16 15:47       833      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-javadoc.jar.md5                 2022-07-16 15:47        32      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-javadoc.jar.sha1                2022-07-16 15:47        40      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-sources.jar                     2022-07-16 15:47     15752      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-sources.jar.asc                 2022-07-16 15:47       833      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-sources.jar.md5                 2022-07-16 15:47        32      
indexer-cli-6.2.2-sources.jar.sha1                2022-07-16 15:47        40      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.jar                             2022-07-16 15:47  12672807      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.jar.asc                         2022-07-16 15:47       833      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.jar.md5                         2022-07-16 15:47        32      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.jar.sha1                        2022-07-16 15:47        40      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.pom                             2022-07-16 15:47      6599      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.pom.asc                         2022-07-16 15:47       833      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.pom.md5                         2022-07-16 15:47        32      
indexer-cli-6.2.2.pom.sha1                        2022-07-16 15:47        40
```

### [Version 7.1.1](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1/):

```
org/apache/maven/indexer/indexer-cli/7.1.1
../
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar                         2023-12-13 22:39  13617488      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar.asc                     2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar.md5                     2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar.sha1                    2023-12-13 22:39        40      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.json                  2023-12-13 22:39     78614      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.json.asc              2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.json.md5              2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.json.sha1             2023-12-13 22:39        40      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.xml                   2023-12-13 22:39     66952      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.xml.asc               2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.xml.md5               2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-cyclonedx.xml.sha1              2023-12-13 22:39        40      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-javadoc.jar                     2023-12-13 22:39    114999      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-javadoc.jar.asc                 2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-javadoc.jar.md5                 2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-javadoc.jar.sha1                2023-12-13 22:39        40      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-sources.jar                     2023-12-13 22:39     17046      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-sources.jar.asc                 2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-sources.jar.md5                 2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1-sources.jar.sha1                2023-12-13 22:39        40      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar                             2023-12-13 22:39     22886      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar.asc                         2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar.md5                         2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.jar.sha1                        2023-12-13 22:39        40      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.pom                             2023-12-13 22:39      6685      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.pom.asc                         2023-12-13 22:39       833      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.pom.md5                         2023-12-13 22:39        32      
indexer-cli-7.1.1.pom.sha1                        2023-12-13 22:39        40
```

There are now far more files then before and the name of the actual executable has changed from `indexer-cli-6.2.2.jar` to `indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar`

Comment: Yes you have to use `indexer-cli-7.1.1-cli.jar` this one..

Comment: @khmarbaise Indeed. An incompatible change the Maven team never bothered to document. It you look at the „Maven :: Indexer CLI“ documentation does not even covert he bare minimum needed to use the application. https://maven.apache.org/maven-indexer/indexer-cli/index.html

Comment: That sounds like a great opportunity to contribute to the docs if you like... and improve them...and make it more usable...