# run the jar file created from windows in linux as executable

Tags: java, linux, jar, executable-jar

Hi I have developed a swing application using `javafx` on Windows operating system . It's working fine on Windows. But when I run the jar on Linux it's defaulting to opening in the archive manager, it's not working as an executable.

I have checked the properties of the jar file, it's an executable already.

Do I have to recompile the source file in a Linux environment to run this `jar file` on Linux or will the `jar file` work on Linux also?

Comment: Please read the link [Executing a jar file in linux][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724953/executing-a-jar-file-in-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you've not used an operating system dependent commands like running a windows command from java (which will not run in linux for sure) or using a windows specific module, your java will run in all other operating systems. This is one of the most significant features of java which is cross-platform and you can run your code in different operating systems which has that operating system specific java runtime environment installed.

So in all operating systems, just you have to run

```
java -jar yourjarfile.jar
```

Comment: when running this command its showing unrecognised class file version

Comment: your java compiler version and java environment version which you are going to run it in, doesn't match. possibly you've compiled in higher version and trying to run in lower ver.

Comment: i think i have compiled in jdk7update11 and running in jdk7 update 10

Comment: now i m running in jdk7 update 11 but its still giving the same error

Comment: @user1960524, are you sure you are running correct version? have you verified using java -version? you may need to run sudo update-java-alternatives -l

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23489/discussion-between-user1960524-and-vahid-farahmand)

Answer (score 0):

executable jar has to be executable across the operating systems.

However, you need to check the permission of the .jar file . especially when executing in linux like environment.

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/java.jar
```

use chmod command in linux / modify your buil.xml using [Ant chmod](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html)

Comment: so how can i make the jar executable across the operating system

Comment: more [info](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/11673-executing-jar-double-click-style-linux.html)