# How to run java application from terminal by simply calling its name?

Tags: java, unix, terminal

I know the default way of calling a jar file from terminal

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I want to call the app from terminal by the name `myapp`. I know its possible to call a shell script from terminal by this method if the script is kept in `/usr/bin/` (And of course the `.sh` extension is removed)

Can this be achieved with jar files? I don't wish to set aliases. I wanted to do this specifically by calling from `bin` directory.

Edit: If its possible to call by something like `java appname`, that shall also be helpful.

Edit: I have checked the usage of linux `gcj` as  Michael Aaron Safyan redirected me in comments. But `gcj` is said to be obsolete for years and is no longer an industry standard.

Can this be achieved by creating a jad file and calling something like `jad myapp` from terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a jar file in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724953/executing-a-jar-file-in-linux)

Comment: What about putting a script in /usr/bin/ that does java -jar PathToMyApp.jar ?

Comment: @RedRoboHood This is not my problem. Please read my question completely. I know how to execute a script and run as `./appname`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a .java or a .jar file into a Linux executable file ( without a .jar extension, which means it's not a .jar file )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429976/how-to-convert-a-java-or-a-jar-file-into-a-linux-executable-file-without-a)

Comment: It doesn't have to be in "/usr/bin", specifically. Any location that is in the "PATH" environment variable would work. You just need a program that will invoke the "java -jar" command (could be BASH script, but it could be a Python script or any other wrapper, for that matter).

Comment: Can the jar file be separate? You could write that shell script you mentioned. Or are you looking for a one file solution?

Comment: @maxwellb Sorry, I didn't understand what you have asked.  May be my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix shells can't run jar files. The only solution to this are a) aliases, or b) writing a minimal wrapper around this, in a file called `myapp`

```
#!/bin/sh

java -jar myapp.jar
```

and putting it in your bin directory. Don't forget to make it executable (`chmod 755 myapp`). You can then call it by `myapp`.

Notice that you can be much cleverer about finding the right version etc. You might simply take such a script from your favourite MIT/BSD licensed Java application, probably, if you include its license with your software.

Comment: Nice answer! That's what I suggested in the comments but was unsure whether that would solve his problem but I couldn't think of any other way to do that

Comment: @Marcus Müller ꕺꕺ This can be helpful. I will go for this if nothing better pops up. Could you please tell me the standard I should follow in unix to place the jar file? Should I put the jar also in `usr/bin/` or in `usr/share/`

Comment: /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/myapp/lib might be semantic and simple enough. Beyond that, you might look into learning pkgconfig.

Comment: @maxwellb Thank you. Will look for this :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to configure Linux to recognize arbitrary file type as executable. I've never done it, but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) is the description of binfmt_misc kernel capability.

That being said, it's a rare java program that does not require setting up a classpath. And that is best accomplished via a shell script wrapper.